# Declined not an answer flag for a low, low quality answer

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, not-an-answer

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59986668/1011527) as "not an answer":

> [image]

But the flag was declined saying *"declined - a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it"*.

I am trying to understand where the line is, was the flag incorrect?

Should I have flagged it as low quality instead? Is the statement "this is impossible and unlikely to happen" considered an "answer", even if it is a bad answer?

Comment: Unfortunately I've learned the hard way that something like that is indeed an answer to the question, albeit wrong and a bad answer. I've also learned never to vote VLQ, because it's almost always denied. Downvote is really the best option here.

Comment: My suggestion would be that the answer *was* actually an answer. The problem with it, however, is that it's very low quality. There's no flag, on answers, for (very) low quality so the best thing to do is downvote it. As a user with a high amount of rep, you can also vote to delete it (once it has a negative score).

Comment: Yes, it is an attempt at answering. It may be a bad answer, but a bad answer is still such an attempt. NAA is for *anything that isn't an attempt at answering*, so things like *Sigh, it's been 12 years and still there is no answer here, did you have a solution yet?* or *but how do I adapt the other answer here to my Rust project?* or *You are all that is wonderful because the answers here saved my pookie from a tree!*

Comment: For bad answers, you **downvote**. They are just unhelpful, but do not need to be fast-tracked for deletion. If the community feels strongly about a specific post, then if downvoted to a score < 0 members [with 20k or more](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/trusted-user) can vote to delete. But it doesn't need to go through the review queues or reach moderators to handle.

Comment: @Larnu There is a VLQ flag for answers. However, after some period of time (I forget) or after it gets upvoted, the VLQ is not available anymore (because the system assumes human decisions on voting are infallible, I guess...)

Comment: You're right, @TylerH . I likely checked an upvoted or older answer. *Why* i can't vote an upvoted answer as low-quality I have no idea. Just because someone is upvoted does not mean it's not low-quality. :/

Comment: @Larnu Yeah, that's my biggest issue with it as well. My second biggest issue is that the flags show up in the mod queue. They should 100% go to a review queue instead.

Comment: Afaik at a point, bad answer becomes NAA, and the border between them can be subjective. This answer lies imho on the border. Furthermore, NAA flags does not go to the mods (in most cases), they go to the VLQ queue, as far I know. Then they can vote to delete (this is a way for users between 2k and 20k to vote to post deletion), if they think it is NAA (or VLQ).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is the statement "this is impossible and unlikely to happen" considered an "answer", even if it is a bad answer?

Yes, bad answers are still answers. That's not the appropriate use for NAA.

That's an actual answer. Yes, it's quite poor. And it's wrong. Downvoting may very well be appropriate.

But moderator action is not required. **No flag is actually warranted**

Voting (regular voting and delete votes) is more than enough to handle the situation.

The post does not fit the definition of "not an answer", and it's understandable that the flag was declined.